# Htaccess rewriting URL - multiple levels

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is probably a duplicate, I'm sorry in advance.

I'm having a bit of a thick moment and need some help with a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ /index.php?name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ /index.php?name=$3 [L]
```

This is currently how we rewrite one of our sites - until we had a bug with 4 levels E.g. /about/company/people/dean.

I could just add another rule to rewrite the 4th level to the index page - but is there a nice way of doing this?

Basically, the overall result - when a url of type '/a/b/c/d/e/f/g' is requested, it will rewrite to '/index.php?name=g' - or whatever is the last element in the url.

Comment: Match **anything**, and direct it to your `index.php` then handle it PHP side with `explode('/', $_GET['name'])`

Comment: That is actually what I do -but I wanted to stay away from (.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick to the end of string anchor. It should catch the last chunk after `/`:

```
RewriteRule .*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ah, this is quite elegant for what he wants, nice.